# How to work with scope for specific functional programming use case PHP

Tags: php

```
$a=function ($y) {
  return function ($x) {
      global $y;
      return $x+$y;
   };
};

echo $a(2)(3);
```

Should echo 5 but echos 3, how to correctly refer to `$y` param in the nested function scope?

Answer (score 4):

You can `use ()` the value of $y in the inner function.  This passes the value from the enclosing scope to the function.

```
$a=function ($y) {
    return function ($x) use ($y) {
        return $x+$y;
    };
};

echo $a(2)(3);
```